# Two functions in one call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, xui

I would like to know if it's possible to do something like that:

```
 x$().xhr('<?php echo $this->createUrl('survey/index', array('id'=>$model->skey)); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: urlstringserialize(serialize(document.getElementById("token-form"))),
                callback: function() {respOK(this.responseText);}
            });
            x$().xhr('<?php echo $this->createUrl('survey/saveBrowser', array('id'=>$model->skey,'browser'=>$browser->getBrowser(),'platform'=>$browser->getPlatform())); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: urlstringserialize(serialize(document.getElementById("token-form"))),
                callback: function() {respOK(this.responseText);}
            });
```

I need to call two different controller functions, one after the other. In this way only the first one is executed.

Comment: aren't you setting yourself up for an inevitable injection attack?

Comment: And what exactly does `x$().xhr` do ?

Comment: How can you confirm > only the first one is executed.< do you handle error ?

Comment: can you show us `respOK` and `x$()` ?

Comment: x$ is used because I'm using xuijs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Execute the second request after the first one, you just need to make the request inside the Callback.

```
 x$().xhr('<?php echo $this->createUrl('survey/index', array('id'=>$model->skey)); ?>', {
        method: 'POST',
        async: true,
        data: urlstringserialize(serialize(document.getElementById("token-form"))),
        callback: function() {
            respOK(this.responseText);
            x$().xhr('<?php echo $this->createUrl('survey/saveBrowser', array('id'=>$model->skey,'browser'=>$browser->getBrowser(),'platform'=>$browser->getPlatform())); ?>', {
                method: 'POST',
                async: true,
                data: urlstringserialize(serialize(document.getElementById("token-form"))),
                callback: function() {respOK(this.responseText);}
            });
});
```

The Problem of the only the first one get called can depend on the Library you are using that seems to be "x$".

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't work for me. Thanks Anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function respOK(data) {
        <?php if($browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_IE) { ?>
        <?php if($campaignCenter->campaign_id == 326) { ?>
            x$("style").remove(".type");
        <?php } ?>
            x$('div.surveyform').html(data);
        <?php } else  { ?>
        <?php if($campaignCenter->campaign_id == 326) { ?>
            x$("style").remove(".type");
        <?php } ?>
            x$('div.surveyform').tween({opacity:0, duration: 200}, function() {x$('div.surveyform').html(data); x$('div.surveyform').tween({opacity: 1, duration: 200});});
        <?php } ?>
    }
```